# Is there anyway to get pdb and Mac Terminal to play nicely?

Tags: python, django, macos, terminal, pdb

When debugging my django apps I use pdb for interactive debugging with `pdb.set_trace()`.

However, when I amend a file the local django webserver restarts and then I cant see what I type in the terminal, until I type `reset`.

Is there anyway for this to happen automatically? It can be real annoying, having to cancel the runserver and reset and restart it all the time.  I'm told it doesn't happen on other OS's (ubuntu) so is there anyway to make it not happen on the Mac?  (I'm using Snow Leopard).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK - this works for me I created a ~/.pdbrc and added

> import os
>    os.system("stty sane")

Now each time pdb is run it sets the line settings back to sane.

If I fall out to the terminal then I still have to do it manually - but it solves having to quit runserver and reset all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Try to [`q`]uit pdb before you save changes to a file.  This will keep the console from wigging out on you but only for that one run of pdb.set_trace().

You will still have to fallback to the old ^C + `reset` + `./manage.py runserver` when you forget to quit pdb.  One thing that can make the reset a little less annoying is to put the reset and runserver onto one line.  That way the reset is just a quick `^Rreset` or up-arrow away.

```
[ ... ]
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
^C$ reset && ./manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 1):

The best I've found is doing a reset inside pdb like so:

> import os; os.system("reset");